# Decrease CRM Solution import and export time

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, crm, dynamics-crm-2013

We have a CRM solution having 132 entities. When we are trying to test it with "MPR Dynamics CRM 2013 Test Tool v4.4.7", solution is failed due to import and export time. It's import time is Apporx. 12 min and export time is more than 45 min. Which is more than allowed by "MPR Dynamics CRM 2013 Test Tool v4.4.7".
Is there any way to decrease this time or we can compress crm solution?

Regards,

Mamta

Comment: I would consider breaking your solution into several modules.

Comment: I would agree with @Zach 's approach

Comment: 132 entities, sounds like a nightmare.  I also agree with @Zach

Answer (score 0):

Mamta, be sure that your solution size is 6 MB MAX.

At least this is the limit on a CRM On-Premises, but this can be increased as needed.

There are also other Tools that helps you export & import from Organization X to Y. For example, you can use XrmToolBox